# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Last night I witnessed something rather peculiar! I'd post a number of records like this one - with no problems at all; but suddenly my Rails app refused to INSERT a particular record into a particular table.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/wdiechmann/63566c838025ab16ed1f) details the result. You may learn that the `abstract_mysql_adapter.rb` does not allow the insert whereas the Rails dbconsole (really the mysql client) does indeed allow the insert?

Does anyone know what goes on? I for one is stumped :(

Comment: It means mysql2 gem did not get this `'\xE5 vide...'` as a utf8 string, set your character set to `utf8`

Comment: The character set of Ruby's database connection was set to something in which the byte sequence `0xE520` was not valid; for example, that byte sequence would not be valid in UTF-8.  You should either transcode the string to the character set of the database connection; or set the database connection to the character set in which your strings are encoded.

Comment: Check default encoding of MySql server and your db. Seems like your problem related to this part of body: `Start p?` where ? - is a symbol in encoding which your DB is not support.

Comment: You can check if  your `database.yml` contains `encoding: utf8` or you can ensure your string before saving to db `force_encoding("UTF-8")`